# How do I used MailApp to attach Images?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to email using the google MailApp Api, here is what I have so far:

```
function myEmailer(mySubject,imgKey) {

  var toEmail ='example@example.com';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: toEmail,
    subject: mySubject,
    attachments:DriveApp.getFileById(imgKey)//this should attach an image from my google drive
   });

}
```

I receive the email just fine, but I don't get an attachment.

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you ID is correct ?

please try this test below :

```
function test(){  
  var mySubject = 'test';
  var imgKey = '0B3qSFd3iikE3Z1ZWcmlWQTFvWDQ'
  myEmailer(mySubject,imgKey) 
}

function myEmailer(mySubject,imgKey) {
  var toEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: toEmail,
    subject: mySubject,
    attachments:DriveApp.getFileById(imgKey).getBlob()//this should attach an image from my google drive
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the wrong Key to pull up the image. Turns out I was trying to pull the key from the folder instead of the image itself.